# Unable to open PDF in Android Chrome browser

Tags: android, jquery, spring, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a different set of forms as pdf dynamically getting populated in mobile and it opens just fine in ios (both safari and chrome) however when i try opening it from android chrome, am getting the following error in chrome in phone.

```
cannot display pdf (test.pdf) is of invalid format
```

In console I get this error,

`org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation`.

Here is my code below. 
private ResponseEntity getPdfResponse(String formRefId, String url){

```
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> resonseEntity = null;
    resonseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, byte[].class);

    byte[] contents  = resonseEntity.getBody();
    String fileName = formRefId+"-form.pdf";
    HttpHeaders headers = getHttpHeaders("application/pdf", fileName);
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> responsePdf = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(contents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return responsePdf;

}
```

Not sure whats causing this.Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `a different set of forms as pdf `. Sorry but i have no idea what that would be. And you are trying to open a pdf file in Chrome browser? Please show used code. I dont understand where you would use Content-Type and Content-Disposition.

Comment: Sorry for that, i have formatted the code properly. Please take a look and help me..

Comment: Is that server code? But i asked you to show how you try to open a pdf file in the Chrome browser. That does not look like such code.